# Google Datastore Transactions are not executed serially

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following code that I need to run in a transaction with serializable isolation level, which according to the documentation is supported by google datastore:

```
class Test(ndb.Model):
    child_ids = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

    @classmethod
    @ndb.transactional()
    def add(cls, parent_id, child_id):
        key = ndb.Key(cls, unicode(child_id.kind()), parent=parent_id)
        # 1
        x = key.get()
        # 2
        if x:
            # 3
            if child_id not in x.child_ids:
                x.child_ids.append(child_id)
                x.put()
        else:
            # 4
            cls(key=key, child_ids=[child_id]).put()
```

"add" is called twice in two different _post_put_hook with the same parent_id and same child_id.kind().

What I'd expect to happen is that only a single entity is created with 2 child_ids (or one of the transactions should fail).

What happens instead is that the last transaction to commit "wins" and child_ids has always only one element. The transaction end up running intertwined like this:

```
T1#1
      T2#1
T1#2
T1#4
      T2#2
      T2#4 <-in a serializable transaction this should fail
```

What's wrong with my code?